# Duplicate bindings with TestInstallIn for instrumented test

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-hilt

I'm using Hilt to inject some dependencies like so:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object SomethingModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideSomething(@ApplicationContext context: Context): Something {
        //return RealSomething
    }
}
```

I want to replace this binding in my tests and following this [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing#replace-binding) I added this fake module to the same folder as my instrumented test:

```
@Module
@TestInstallIn(
    components = [SingletonComponent::class],
    replaces = [SomethingModule::class]
)
object FakeSomethingModuleModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideSomethingModule(): Something {
        return FakeSomething()
    }
}
```

When I try to run my instrumented test the build fails with a duplicate binding error:

```
error: [Dagger/DuplicateBindings] com.example.Something is bound multiple times:
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements HiltWrapper_ActivityRetainedComponentManager_ActivityRetainedComponentBuilderEntryPoint,
```

Commenting out the Fake Module fixes the issue. Anyone see what I'm missing here?

EDIT: Just tried with `@UninstallModules` and ran into the same build error:

```
@UninstallModules(SomethingModule::class)
@HiltAndroidTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyInstrumentedTest {

    @Module
    @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    object FakeSomethingModule {

        @Provides
        fun provideSomthing(): Something = FakeSomething()
    }
```

Comment: `Something is bound multiple times` this issue is because you are providing `Something` dependency from two different modules. You can remove SomethingModule from your test module.

Comment: @0xAliHn I'm trying to replace a module in a test, the second module is intentional. `TestInstallIn` is a feature of Hilt that allows you to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried lots of different things in order to finally get to a solution:

1. Make sure the fake implementations have `@Inject constructor()`
2. In the test `@Module` use `@Binds` and an abstract class instead of `@Provides`
3. You don't need a component that combines all your modules, this code is not necessary:

```
@Module(
    includes = [ <modules> ]
```

4. It wasn't apparent in this sample but in my actual code the module I was trying to test was included as a binding to another class using `@Module(includes = SomethingBinding)`. I created a module just for the object I wanted to mock in my instrumented tests

Comment: With these requirements `@TestInstallIn` is quite useless for many things. I have been trying to get it working with Room DB and continuously failing. The class is in a library so I am unable to modify it. To construct an instance one needs to call a factory function from Room, so `@Provides` is necessary. I want to provide an in-memory version of the DB in tests. Did you figure out any way to get it working with `@Provides`?